# What is the purpose of org.openqa.selenium.remote.session.StripAnyPlatform class in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am seeing information about the class org.openqa.selenium.remote.session.StripAnyPlatform under selenium javadoc. But I am not able to understand the use of it. Google search is not giving proper information. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for use with [Selenium Remote](https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/).  The Platform you are using in your Remote instance are stored in a `Map` object.

Thus, what org.openqa.selenium.remote.session.StripAnyPlatform does is simply set that Map object to null.